# is this a bad Core Data pattern for sharing functionality?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

I have an app and there is some basic functionality that needs to be shared across several controllers, one being adding and removing what I call BookmarkedObjects to my data store.  So I created the following funciton and it seems to be working really well and I would like to apply this pattern to other function in my code like adding objects to an order, seeing if an order already exist ect..

Here is what I am doing:

```
+(void) RemoveBookmark: (NSString *) aItemID  withCustomerNumber: (NSString *) aCustomerNumber withManufacturerID: (NSString *) aManufacturerID withManagedObjectContext: (NSManagedObjectContext *) aContext {
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"BookmarkedItem" inManagedObjectContext:aContext]];
    [request setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"CustomerNumber==%@ AND ManufacturerID==%@ AND ItemID==%@", aCustomerNumber, aManufacturerID, aItemID]];
    [request setFetchLimit:1];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *results = [aContext executeFetchRequest:request    error:&error];
    [request release], request = nil;
    [aContext deleteObject:[results lastObject]];
    [aContext save:&error];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you to make a singleton class and add all such type of function in it.The main benefit of its is that all class methods are loaded on compile time so if there are 5 such functions the your app will take up unnecessary memory, so I'll suggest you something 
like this 
Define a class named SharedFunctions

in .h

```
@interface SharedFunctions : NSObject
{
}
+(SharedFunctions*)sharedInstance;
-(void)yourFunction;
.....
//make as many instace methods as you want
@end
```

in .m

```
@implementation SharedFunctions
static SharedFunctions* singletonInstance = nil;

-(id)init
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {

    }
    return self;
}


+(SharedFunctions*)sharedInstance
{
    @synchronized(self) {
        if (singletonInstance == nil) 
        {
        singletonInstance =  [[SharedFunctions alloc] init]; 
        }
    }
    return singletonInstance;
}

///and define your methods 
-(void)yourFunction
{
       //somthing
}
@end
```

Now to use your methods just call

```
 [[SharedFunctions sharedInstance] yourFunction];
```

By this way all such methods are at one place and there is only one class method so no memory issue.